# What's the best solution for Hive proxy user in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hive, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I'm very confusing by the proxyuser setting in HDFS and Hive. I have the doAs option enabled in hive-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

And proxyuser in core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
```

But this will cause:

```
2017-03-29 16:24:59,022 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Connection from 172.16.0.239:60920 for protocol org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol is unauthorized for user hive (auth:PROXY) via hive (auth:SIMPLE)
2017-03-29 16:24:59,023 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Socket Reader #1 for port 9000: readAndProcess from client 172.16.0.239 threw exception [org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive]
```

I didn't set proxyuser to "hive" like most example saying is because core-site.xml is shared by other services, I don't like every service access HDFS as hive, but I still gave it a try so that now the core-site.xml looks as:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
```

I lunched beeline again, however, the login is fine this time, but when a command was running, yarn thrown exception:

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. Permission denied: user=hive, access=WRITE, inode="/user/yarn/hive/.staging":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

proxyuser "hive" has been denied from the staging folder which is owned by "hdfs". I don't think give 777 to the staging folder is a good idea as it makes no sense to give HDFS protection but open the folder to everyone. So my question is what's the best solution to setup the permission between Hive, Hdfs and Yarn?

Hadoop permission is just a nightmare to me, please help.

Comment: @BruceWayne you are not answering my question. I hate 777, what I can do is to set "/user/yarn/hive" 's owner to "hive", but now history server has trouble, when user "yarn" is trying to access "/user/yarn/history/temp/hive" to read the log, but it is owning by "hive", I got "Permission denied" again.

Comment: @franklinsijo The folder didn't exist before, and "hive" tried to create it but encountered permission issue, as /user/yarn is owned by "yarn". However, I manually created it and assigned the owner to "hive", but now the problem happens to history server which is owned by "yarn" also, and was trying to access the log files which created by "hive".

Comment: No, hive's warehouse is under "/user/hive/warehouse", owned by hive.

Comment: @franklinsijo yes, the staging-dir is setting in mapred-site.xml, which is under /user/yarn, I think it is reasonable, as it is designed to be managed by yarn.

Comment: @franklinsijo, that maybe good idea, but still not fix my problem. Even though we are able to bypass folder restriction, the history server still can't access .jhist which was created by hive also.

Comment: You would see "Permission denied: user=yarn, access=READ, inode="/user/yarn/history/temp/hive/job_1490820028505_0002.summary":hive:supergroup:-rwxrwx---"

Comment: Agree, that's what I'm going to try, but how I can name the group for user yarn?

Comment: I mean how I can let system know "yarn" is a superuser?

Comment: @franklinsijo I cann't do that as the account is controlled by infrastructure team. Is there any way to add "yarn" to Hadoop's default supergroup? just like "hdfs".

Comment: @franklinsijo I see, but the problem is I'm not able to create group within the OS, I mean am I able to "tell" HADOOP a user belongs to a certain group on the fly without explicitly create a "supergroup" group on the OS? just like HADOOP_USER_NAME does for the username, but I tried HADOOP_GROUP_NAME, it looks doesn't work.

Comment: Very helpful, @franklinsijo, add supergroup resolved the folder permission issue. You should add your answer to the post so that you will get reputation. But rollback to the very beginning, if I remove proxyuser from core-site.xml as I don't want every one out of hive will be proxied as "hive" also, I still got `User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive` issue.

Comment: @user3593261 Updated the answer. dropping the long string of comments conversation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding proxyuser entries in `core-site.xml` would allow the superuser named `hive` to connect from any host (as value is `*`) to impersonate a user belonging to any group (as value is `*`).

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
```

This can be made more restrictive by passing actual hostnames and group names (Refer [Superusers](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Superusers.html)). The access privileges the superuser `hive` has on the FS will be applicable for the impersonating users.

For a multi-user Hadoop environment, the best practice would be to create dedicated directories for every superuser and configure the associated service to store files in it. And create a group `supergroup` for all these superusers so that group level access privileges can be given for the files, if required.

Add this property in `hdfs-site.xml` to configure the supergroup

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
   <value>supergroup</value> 
   <description>The name of the group of super-users.</description>
</property>
```